# Xcode 11.4 - Why my application size is increased from 8 MB to 80 MB with just iOS 12.0 support

Tags: ios, swift5, xcode11.4

I just add changed the target from 13.4 - 12.0 and my app size is size from 8 MB to 80 MB.

[image]

Can I reduce the size again with iOS 12 support?

[image]

Comment: Probably because old OS needs you to include the Swift frameworks in the app.  The AppStore will be smart enough to thin your app so that iOS13 downloads will still be small

Comment: If your app uses any Swift at all, @LouFranco's comment is the answer. Swift 5 introduced ABI stability, which means that Apple was able to start embedding the frameworks the system needs to run Swift code in the operating system itself as of iOS 13. Prior to that, the Swift runtime libraries had to be compiled and shipped with each individual app, which were *very* large

Comment: To add to that, while the output from Xcode is 86mb, what the users will download will be a fraction of that once Apple have thinned it. One of my apps is 200mb uploaded, but only requires an 80mb download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that your app uses Swift and the IPA needs to include the Swift framework for old OS versions.

But, not to worry, your IPA contains everything that any device could possibly need, but the App Store makes thinned versions so that users only download what they need.

To get an idea of what that would be, upload your IPA to AppStoreConnect and look in the "Activity" section of your app.  Choose the build, and then look under "Compressed File Size" and click "App Store File Sizes" which will give you download and install size.

[image]